# How can I keep screen on ONLY while music is playing?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-maps, screen-timeout, pandora

I drive typically 300+miles a day and my phone works both as my GPS and my media player through my work trucks AUX port. I drive to a lot of the same places so after awhile the GPS isn't kept on top and just stays running in the background to warn me if there's a faster route than usual due to accidents or traffic. Thus I'd rather let Google Maps run in the background and have Pandora on screen to make it easy to up and down vote songs without anything more than a quick glance, I drive a large truck so the whole picking up my phone, turning the screen on, entering my pin, etc is not a valid solution to me. Yet if Google Maps isn't on screen the screen will eventually dim and turn off. Does anyone know of an app or workaround that would keep the screen on while Pandora is running? Maybe something with extra features such as only if Pandora is running and the phone is charging. I'm aware of the "Keep screen on while charging" option but thanks to me having a crappy Samsung (Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 6.0.1) this means when my phone is finished charging at night the screen turns on and stays on waking me up. My only request is please only give valid answers, no "Sorry not possible.", "Don't mess with your phone while driving.", "Just deal with the screen turning on at night.", etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pandora, you need to uncheck "Conserve battery option" option under the Menu > Settings > Advanced. Now the screen will stay on while the music is playing on Pandora.

You can also download the apps like [KeepScreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tni.KeepScreenLite) and [Stay Alive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synetics.stay.alive&hl=en) to block screen timeout when predefined applications are active.